# How to get attribute values from html in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

The followings is angular js file for routing and I allocate the accessible roles to access each menu.

```
angular.module('RedCA')
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $scope, $rootScope) {

     // For unmatched routes
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    // Application routes
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.tpl.html'
                ,
            controller : 'AlertsCtrl',
            access: routingConfig.accessLevels.user,
            data: {
                rule: function(user) {
                    if(user == '') return true;
                    else return false;

            }
            },
            title : 'DashBoard'
        })

        .state('tables', {
            url: '/tables',
            templateUrl: 'templates/tables.tpl.html',
            access: routingConfig.accessLevels.admin,
            title : 'Tables'
        })

               .state('changeSave', {
            url: '/changeSave',
            templateUrl: 'change/changeSave.tpl.html',
            controller : 'changeSaveCtrl',
            access: routingConfig.accessLevels.user
        })
        .state('changeView', {
            url: '/changeView',
            templateUrl: 'change/changeView.tpl.html',
            controller : 'changeViewCtrl',
            access: routingConfig.accessLevels.anon
        })
```

The followings is index.html. I allocate the roles to access the page, again.

```
<li data-access-level="accessLevels.user" active-nav><a href="#/changeMasterList">view 1</a></li>
                <li data-access-level="accessLevels.user" active-nav><a href="#/changeSave">view 2</a></li>
                <li data-access-level="accessLevels.user" active-nav><a href="#/subRepUserReg">view 3</a></li>
```

How can I retrieve the role that I already allocated from the one in the another  one?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What does `data-access-level` do? Where does routingConfig come from? Maybe a simple explanation of what you'd expect to happen would help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand the question entirely it could use some clarification.  In general if you're trying to share information between multiple controllers you want to define some sort of a provider (typically a factory or service).  You can get details on [providers here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers).

Here's a plnkr I just wrote up for another question that shows a factory being defined for sharing data and being injected into a controller.

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
  .factory('MyDataService', function($http){
    //Using $http here to do the AJAX request

    var service = {};

    service.getData = function(){
      return $http.get('data.json').then(function(resp){
        service.data = resp.data;
      })
    }

    service.getData();

    return service;
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', function(MyDataService) {
    this.MyDataService = MyDataService;
  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4NYFJ03ldsISSNF3aqoB?p=preview

Comment: We seem to be looking at all the same questions right now. :)